# Change data frame value

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a data frame table (2 columns, and 129 rows):

| sentence | word |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 289 |
| 0 | 2 |
| 0 | 22 |
| 0 | 23 |

several of the values in the sentence column has a value of 0, I want to increase all the values of 0 to 1.

Answer (score 1):

Use boolean-indexing:

```py
mask = df["sentence"].eq(0)
df.loc[mask, "sentence"] += 1
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   sentence  word
0        10   289
1         1     2
2         1    22
3         1    23
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `mask` method of `DataFrame`

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> x = pd.DataFrame({'sentence' : [0,1,2,3], 'word' : [4,5,0,6]})
>>> x
   sentence  word
0         0     4
1         1     5
2         2     0
3         3     6
>>> x['sentence'].mask(x['sentence'] == 0, 1, inplace=True)
>>> x
   sentence  word
0         1     4
1         1     5
2         2     0
3         3     6
```